# How to generate a random integer that is either 0 or 1 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I searched the MATLAB documentation for how to generate a random integer that is either a 0 or a 1.

I stumbled upon the two functions randint and randi.
randint appears to be deprecated in my version of MATLAB although it is in the documentation online and randi appears to only create randoms numbers between 1 and a specified imax value.

I even created my own randint function to solve the problem although it doesn't run very efficiently in my program since it is used for large data sets:

```
function [ints] = randint(m,n)
ints = round(rand(m,n));
end
```

Is there a built-in function to create a random integer that is either a 0 or 1 or is there a more efficient way to create such a function in MATLAB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a little faster:

```
result = rand(m,n)<.5;
```

Or, if you need the result as `double`:

```
result = double(rand(m,n)<.5);
```

Examples with `m = 100`, `n = 1e5` (Matlab 2010b):

```
>> tic, round(rand(m,n)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.494488 seconds.

>> tic, randi([0 1], m,n); toc
Elapsed time is 0.565805 seconds.

>> tic, rand(m,n)<.5; toc
Elapsed time is 0.365703 seconds.

>> tic, double(rand(m,n)<.5); toc
Elapsed time is 0.445467 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 Mostly because I had to use it or rather steal it here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25042451/3293881, so thank you! :). Hope that's okay by the way!

Comment: `<.5` is fastest because I think it simply perform an assembly `JL` while others are all made up from bunch of instructions.

Answer (score 4):

`randi` is the way to go, just define the boundaries to **1** and **0**

```
A = randi([0 1], m, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate either 0 or 1 randomly...

x=round(rand)